# Bootstrap Carousel if item active add class to div then remove

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a Bootstrap Carousel and I've added a class of `testing` to `.link-txt` depending on if .`item` is `.active`. However I want to remove the class from `.link-txt` once `.active` is removed from that specific .`item`. I don't seem to be able to remove the class with an if `hasClass`

Here is my jQuery so far:

```
$('#home-carousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function() {
    if ($('.item').hasClass('active')) {
     $('.active .link-txt').addClass('testing');
    } else {
     $('.link-txt').removeClass('testing');
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<?php
if( have_rows('carousel') ):?>
<div id="home-carousel" class="carousel bs-slider fade  control-round indicators-line" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="6000">
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <?php 
    $i=0;
    while ( have_rows('carousel') ) : the_row();?>
        <div class="item  <?php if($i === 0) { ?> active <?php } ?>" style="background-image:url(<?php the_sub_field('image'); ?>);">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <div class="col-md-6 ">
                    <h1><a href="<?php the_sub_field('link');?>"><?php the_sub_field('heading');?></a></h1>        
                    <a href="<?php the_sub_field('link');?>" class="link-txt">View</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php 
    ++$i; 
    endwhile; ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif;?>
```

Alongside not being able remove the class `testing`.... I've also spotted the first slide with `.active` is added into the HTML, but this doesn't seem to be detected with the jQuery. Meaning the class isn't added until the 2nd slide. Is there a way to detect `.active` on the first slide and add testing to `.link-txt`?

[Here is Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m2Lx7cm1/1/) showing the issue.

Comment: With `$('.link-txt').addClass('testing');` you add the class to all elements .link-text because you did not select a specific one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function linkClass() {
  $('.item .link-txt').removeClass('testing') //Remove every class no check necessary
  $('.item.active .link-txt').addClass('testing'); //Add the class to the active one
}

//Document ready so it works also on startup
$( document ).ready(function() {
    linkClass();
});

$('#home-carousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function() {linkClass()});
```

It already works on first slide, your problem is just that it does not slide on the creation. So I added an document ready function so it will work also on startup.

**EDIT:** This example I have copied from https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_carousel.asp 
I added my code and if you open it with the developer console you will see it does exactly what you want.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  .carousel-inner > .item > img,
  .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
      width: 70%;
      margin: auto;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Carousel Events - slid.bs.carousel</h2>
  <p>The <strong>slid.bs.modal</strong> event occurs when the carousel has finished sliding from one item to another.</p>
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li class="item1 active"></li>
      <li class="item2"></li>
      <li class="item3"></li>
      <li class="item4"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/360x150" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
      </div>
    
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/370x150" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/380x150" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Activate Carousel
    $("#myCarousel").carousel();
    
    // Enable Carousel Indicators
    $(".item1").click(function(){
        $("#myCarousel").carousel(0);
    });
    $(".item2").click(function(){
        $("#myCarousel").carousel(1);
    });
    $(".item3").click(function(){
        $("#myCarousel").carousel(2);
    });
    $(".item4").click(function(){
        $("#myCarousel").carousel(3);
    });
    
    // Enable Carousel Controls
    $(".left").click(function(){
        $("#myCarousel").carousel("prev");
    });
    $(".right").click(function(){
        $("#myCarousel").carousel("next");
    });

    $("#myCarousel").on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
        $('.item img').removeClass('testing') //Remove every class no check necessary
        $('.item.active img').addClass('testing');
    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry my mistake, its only adding the class testing to the first .item .link-txt, which it doesn't remove and then its not adding a class to the other .item .link-txt

Comment: @probablybest Does the class active changes on every slide ? Or does it eventually stay on the first item ?

Comment: @Doomenik thanks for adding the example. I have put together a JSFiddle showing what I'm doing. I still dont seem to be able to get it to work https://jsfiddle.net/m2Lx7cm1/1/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5qx1n22g/ Here is your updated fiddle, I changed also the code in the answer. @probablybest